# How to use salesforce translation cache?

Tags: salesforce, teiid

If we use salesforce translator need to use cache for translation results (not for query results) for speed up of translation of SQL request to SOQL. How to use this in TEIID in spring-boot-teiid application?

Comment: Have you seen this taking a long time? have any debug info? You can turn on the prepared statement cache, but that is only at engine level.

Comment: How i can turn on cache?

Comment: There is no cache at the level of SQL to SOQL, if you are seeing generally an issue with performance, then this could be some other issue, we need to details as to how you came to the conclusion that you need cache at SOQL layer.